# Adding and specifying legend to the multiple chart.rolling Correlation plots

Tags: r, plot, performanceanalytics

For simplicity, suppose I have the following `zoo` object:

```
x.ts<- structure(c(103.7, 103.2, 103.1, 105.4, 102.1, 103.5, 103.1, 
102.6, 102.2, 104.6, -2.1, -1, -3, 2, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 0, -25, 
-25, -25, -25, -25, -25, -21, -21, -20, -20), .Dim = c(10L, 3L
), .Dimnames = list(c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", 
"9", "10"), c("a", "b", "c")), index = structure(c(1985, 1985.08333333333, 
1985.16666666667, 1985.25, 1985.33333333333, 1985.41666666667, 
1985.5, 1985.58333333333, 1985.66666666667, 1985.75), class = "yearmon"), class = "zoo")
```

I am interested in plotting the rolling correlation between each pairs of the time series in the object. I used `chart.RollingCorrelation` from `PerformanceAnalytics` package and plot the charts as follow:

```
par.corr<-par(mfrow=c(1,2), oma = c(1, 1, 1, 1), mar = c(2, 2, 2, 2))
chart.RollingCorrelation(x.ts[, 1, drop=FALSE],
                         x.ts[, 1:3, drop=FALSE],
                         colorset=rich8equal,legend.loc = "right",
                         width=3, main = "a to b and c")
chart.RollingCorrelation(x.ts[, 2, drop=FALSE],
                         x.ts[, c(1,3), drop=FALSE],
                         colorset=rich8equal,legend.loc = "right",
                         width=3, main = "b to a and c")
mtext("Rolling 3 Month Correlation", side=3, line=-0.3, outer=TRUE, cex=1.2)
par(par.corr)
```

I get the following plot:

[image: Rolling Correlation]

I need to get a common legend for both charts with one colour describing each relationship and place it to the bottom of the plot. I have tried to remove the legend specification from the `chart.RollingCorrelation`'s arguments and add another plot with my customised legend but there is an issue with that. Because every chart in the plot has been plotted separately, you will find that two different relationships are represented by the same colour. So it seems I need to change something in the way I apply the function.

Comment: would it work if you manually assigned the colors as opposed to the automatic assignment of `colorset=rich8equal`? for instance, for the first plot put in `colorset=c(1,2)` and for the second plot put in `colorset=c(1,3)`. Unless you see a need to automate the process as you're dealing with a bigger data frame and this is just a simplified version. It would help if you could provide some context.

Comment: @salhin you ever figure this out?